# Rlogin prompting for remote password (Kali / Metasploitable)

Tags: ssh, kali-linux, metasploit

I am following a tutorial that can be found here.

http://www.kalitutorials.net/2014/05/metasploitable-2-vulnerability.html

Specifically the "Remote access vulnerability - Rlogin" section.

When I run the command "rlogin -l root 192.168.154.132"

I get a password prompt, as per the below

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.154.132 (192.168.154.132)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is *****.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.154.132' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@192.168.154.132's password:
```

The tutorial states "It's because we don't have ssh-client installed on Kali Linux"

However when I try to install the client, using the following command "apt-get install rsh-client", I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'openssh-client' instead of 'rsh-client'
openssh-client is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have tried running "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade" to make sure everything is up to date.

I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing the openssh client.

However I continue to get prompted by the password box (which according to the tutorial I should not)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was solved by doing this :-

1. Update the package index:

   ```
   # sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install rsh-client deb package:

   ```
   # sudo apt-get install rsh-client
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:

```
system ssh start
```

then check if it is active by typing in `service --status-all`
If there is `a +` next to SSH it is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Even though M2 tutorial offers you a walk though, please leave a room for some challenges:  "rlogin -l root 192.168.154.132" is asking you for a "root" user password, right? Check out /etc/issue and think about it... think of username that M2 is using..

Comment: While some of those might be helpful thoughts to consider, this doesn't really provide an answer to the question, and so would be better off as a comment.